# Calculate value of percentage sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table.

```
  orderid  processid uid   user     processdesc  companyname     ordervalue perwet  orgid
   1    1   16  Damayanti   Enquiry Synechron   33000   10.00   NULL
   1    2   4   Meghana Requirement Synechron   33000   10.00   NULL
   1    3   5   Yogini  Proposal FollowUp   Synechron   33000   10.00   NULL
   1    4   5   Yogini  Order   Synechron   33000   20.00   NULL
   1    5   4   Meghana Vendor Management   Synechron   33000   10.00   NULL
   1    6   1   anaghantech Collection  Synechron   33000   20.00   NULL
   2    1   4   Meghana Enquiry test    100000  10.00   NULL
   2    2   4   Meghana Requirement test    100000  10.00   NULL
   2    3   5   Yogini  Proposal FollowUp   test    100000  10.00   NULL
   2    4   4   Meghana Order   test    100000  20.00   NULL
   2    5   4   Meghana Vendor Management   test    100000  10.00   NULL
   2    6   1   anaghantech Collection  test    100000  6.67    NULL
   2    6   4   Meghana Collection  test    100000  6.67    NULL
   2    6   16  Damayanti   Collection  test    100000  6.67    NULL
   5    1   16  Damayanti   Enquiry FASTER HYDRAULICS PVT. LTD. 700000  10.00   NULL
   5    2   16  Damayanti   Requirement FASTER HYDRAULICS PVT. LTD. 700000  10.00   NULL
   5    3   16  Damayanti   Proposal FollowUp   FASTER HYDRAULICS PVT. LTD. 700000  10.00   NULL
   5    4   16  Damayanti   Order   FASTER HYDRAULICS PVT. LTD. 700000  20.00   NULL
```

I want to add one more column to this table

like `perwet/100 * ordervalue`

using the query given below

```
SELECT a.orderid, 
       b.processid, 
       b.uid, 
       d.username, 
       c.processdesc, 
       a.companyname, 
       b.ordervalue, 
       b.perwet, 
       b.orgid 
FROM   ordermaster a, 
       temp_calpoints1 b, 
       process c, 
       userinfo d 
WHERE  a.orderid = b.orderid 
       AND c.processid = b.processid 
       AND d.uid = b.uid 
ORDER  BY b.orderid, 
          b.processid, 
          b.uid;
```

Comment: Would this simple be a calculated column based on values in the same row? You might then want to look at using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use VIEW instead of adding a new column to your table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
SELECT a.orderid, 
       b.processid, 
       b.uid, 
       d.username, 
       c.processdesc, 
       a.companyname, 
       b.ordervalue, 
       b.perwet, 
       b.orgid,

       MyField = b.perwet / 100 * b.ordervalue

FROM   ordermaster a, 
       temp_calpoints1 b, 
       process c, 
       userinfo d 
WHERE  a.orderid = b.orderid 
       AND c.processid = b.processid 
       AND d.uid = b.uid
```

Comment: Not hating on your solution, but why do you do your join stuff in the where clause rather than using joins? Is this an old person thing?

Comment: @Scotch ask OP about that. It's his query

Comment: Gotcha, I just see people doing that a lot on here, I was wondering if its just old habits from a time when join syntax possibly didn't exist.

Comment: @Scotch - It's an old style (inner) join and it is discouraged to use them. It is far more readable to be explicit about your joins and write them as such.